# HTML5 Fullscreen API - DIV doesnt scroll

Tags: html, api, fullscreen

Im doing research on mobile apps. When the fullscreen api is active, im allowed to scroll my div on firefox desktop but not on mobile firefox. It looks like everything is freezed.

Someone know how to fix this ? Or is this just something the browser doesnt support?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using?

First i've heard about this fullscreen API, but according to the docs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode, it states it isn't enabled by default in Firefox mobile 9, but it is in version 10.